# Error: Try expected. ts(1005). while implementing login/signup using firebase in react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication

I am learning react using a youtube playlist and while working on a login signup page using firebase my VSCode shows the following Error.

```
Declaration or statement expected.ts(1128)
'try' expected.ts(1005)
```

But I can not see the same error in the Video while he guys was explaining the things. I don't why its happening. I have latest version of tsc installed and tsc --version returns "Version 4.2.2", so there is no issue regarding old compiler version.
Please help me sort out this.

Here is my login.js (not complete yet)

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import '../../static/login.css';
import fire from '../../fire';

const login =()=>{
    const[user, setUser]= useState('');
    const[email, setEmail]= useState('');
    const[password, setPassword]= useState('');
    const[emailErr, setEmailErr]= useState('');
    const[passwordErr, setPasswordErr]= useState('');
    const[hasAccount, sethasAccount]= useState(false);

    const handleLogin=()=>{
        fire
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password);
        .catch((err)=>{                               //THIS STATEMENT SHOWS ERROR
            switch(err.code){
                case "auth/invalid-email":
                case "auth/user-disabled":
                case "auth/user-not-found":
                    setEmailErr(err.message);
                    break;
                case "auth/wrong-password":
                    setPasswordErr(err.message);
                    break;
            }
        });
    };

    return(
        <div>Login Page</div>
    );
};

export default login;
```

Comment: You have a semi colon at the end of the line above

Comment: I guess all the semicolons are correct. Which semicolon are you talking about?

Comment: `.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password);` this semi-colin means that the function chain is broken for the next line.